# Can't compile unmodified Android from source

Tags: java, android, build, android-source

I'm trying to compile Android from source with no modifications.  I've followed all the Google walk through's and all the posts I can find about java versions but still get what seems like the same errors.  I've tried many times to build it, triple checking settings and java versions, but am at a loss.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm running 16Gb RAM and have tried different -jX commands including omitting it completely.  Here's the top of my build, and the last part of the log.

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.4.2
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_arm
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-3.13.0-39-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=KOT49H
OUT_DIR=/ssd/android/build/android
============================================
```

and the later part of the output

```
Processing target/product/generic/obj/APPS/DeskClock_intermediates/package.apk
Done!
Install: /ssd/android/build/android/target/product/generic/system/app/DeskClock.odex
Install: /ssd/android/build/android/target/product/generic/system/app/DeskClock.apk
target Java: junit-runner (/ssd/android/build/android/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/junit-runner_intermediates/classes)
Copying: /ssd/android/build/android/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/junit-runner_intermediates/classes-jarjar.jar
Copying: /ssd/android/build/android/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/junit-runner_intermediates/emma_out/lib/classes-jarjar.jar
Copying: /ssd/android/build/android/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/junit-runner_intermediates/classes.jar
target Static Jar: junit-runner (/ssd/android/build/android/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/junit-runner_intermediates/javalib.jar)
target Java: android.test.runner (/ssd/android/build/android/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android.test.runner_intermediates/classes)
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Copying: /ssd/android/build/android/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android.test.runner_intermediates/classes-jarjar.jar
Copying: /ssd/android/build/android/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android.test.runner_intermediates/emma_out/lib/classes-jarjar.jar
Copying: /ssd/android/build/android/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android.test.runner_intermediates/classes.jar
target Java: Development (/ssd/android/build/android/target/common/obj/APPS/Development_intermediates/classes)
/ssd/android/build/android/target/common/obj/APPS/Development_intermediates/src/src/com/android/development/IRemoteService.java:6: duplicate class: com.android.development.IRemoteService
public interface IRemoteService extends android.os.IInterface
       ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
make: *** [/ssd/android/build/android/target/common/obj/APPS/Development_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar] Error 41
```

I am running oracles java6 versions, and all update-alternatives are set correctly I believe.  I've cleaned and re-made the project with the same results.  It seems this shouldn't be such a problem to make with no modifications to the sync'd code.

On another note I was able to successfully build the Cyanogenmod version of the OS so I know my steps aren't off, I'd still appreciate any suggestions on the original source?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I finally got this working.  Turns out the best solution was to ignore most of the suggestions found about using Java 6 and Sun's version and just wipe java completely, re-install OpenJDK-7.  After verifying my JAVA_HOME directory, verifying my PATH directories for Java, re running the repo sync to the master branch, resetting all my update-alternatives to verify they were Java OpenJDK-7 and re issuing the commands (source, lunch) then making (I only used -j4 option) and letting it run overnight (I don't know how long it took) it finally built.  Hopefully this helps someone at some point, it's been quite the challenge for a basic download and build without changes.